# Constant deletion routine can harm the performance of the database or application?

Tags: python, sql, django, sqlite, django-views

I created a view that does some checks between models as these models are updated/added.
When this check finds an inconsistency it creates a record and a specific model of record of inconsistencies.
My question is about the strategy I used in this view.

**view**

```
def farm_check(farm_id):
    farm = get_object_or_404(Farm, pk=farm_id)
    to_delete = FarmProblem.objects.filter(farm=farm)
    for delete in to_delete:
        delete.delete()
    check_city = Registration.objects.filter(farm=farm).filter(~Q(city=farm.city))
    check_uf = Registration.objects.filter(farm=farm).filter(~Q(uf=farm.uf))
    check_car = Registration.objects.filter(farm=farm,car__isnull=True)
    check_ccir = Registration.objects.filter(farm=farm,ccir__isnull=True)
    check_nirf = Registration.objects.filter(farm=farm,nirf__isnull=True)
    check_area = Registration.objects.filter(farm=farm,area__isnull=True)
    list_area_pk = map(lambda x: x.pk,check_area)
    check_app = Registration.objects.filter(farm=farm,app__isnull=True).exclude(pk__in=list_area_pk)
    for check in check_city:
        problem = 'Cidade inconsistente'
        item_test = FarmProblem.objects.filter(client=farm.client,farm=farm,context='City',specific=check.number,item=problem)
        if not item_test:
            item = FarmProblem(client=farm.client,farm=farm,context='City',specific=check.number,item=problem)
            item.save()
    for check in check_uf:
        problem = 'UF inconsistente'
        item_test = FarmProblem.objects.filter(client=farm.client,farm=farm,context='UF',specific=check.number,item=problem)
        if not item_test:
            item = FarmProblem(client=farm.client,farm=farm,context='UF',specific=check.number,item=problem)
            item.save()
    for check in check_car:
        problem = 'CAR inconsistente'
        item_test = FarmProblem.objects.filter(client=farm.client,farm=farm,context='CAR',specific=check.number,item=problem)
        if not item_test:
            item = FarmProblem(client=farm.client,farm=farm,context='CAR',specific=check.number,item=problem)
            item.save()
    for check in check_ccir:
        problem = 'CCIR inconsistente'
        item_test = FarmProblem.objects.filter(client=farm.client,farm=farm,context='CCIR',specific=check.number,item=problem)
        if not item_test:
            item = FarmProblem(client=farm.client,farm=farm,context='CCIR',specific=check.number,item=problem)
            item.save()
    for check in check_nirf:
        problem = 'Sem número de NIRF'
        item_test = FarmProblem.objects.filter(client=farm.client,farm=farm,context='NIRF',specific=check.number,item=problem)
        if not item_test:
            item = FarmProblem(client=farm.client,farm=farm,context='NIRF',specific=check.number,item=problem)
            item.save()
    for check in check_area:
        problem = 'Área indeterminada'
        item_test = FarmProblem.objects.filter(client=farm.client,farm=farm,context='Area',specific=check.number,item=problem)
        if not item_test:
            item = FarmProblem(client=farm.client,farm=farm,context='Area',specific=check.number,item=problem)
            item.save()
    for check in check_app:
        problem = 'APP indeterminada'
        item_test = FarmProblem.objects.filter(client=farm.client,farm=farm,context='APP',specific=check.number,item=problem)
        if not item_test:
            item = FarmProblem(client=farm.client,farm=farm,context='APP',specific=check.number,item=problem)
            item.save()
    
    """ OWNERS """

    registrations = Registration.objects.filter(farm=farm).annotate(part_total=Sum('registrationowner__part'))
    for registration in registrations:
        if registration.part_total != 100:
            problem = 'Soma das cotas dos proprietários diferente de 100%'
            item = FarmProblem(client=registration.client,farm=farm,context='Registration Owner',specific=registration.number,item=problem)
            item.save()

    for registration in registrations:
        if registration.car:
            registration_owners = RegistrationOwner.objects.filter(farm=farm,registration=registration)
            registration_owners = list(map(lambda x: [x.name,x.cpf] if x.person=='PF' else [x.name,x.cnpj],registration_owners))
            car_owners = CAROwner.objects.filter(farm=farm).filter(car__number=registration.car)
            car_owners = list(map(lambda x: [x.name,x.cpf] if x.person=='PF' else [x.name,x.cnpj],car_owners))
            for registration_owner in registration_owners:
                if registration_owner not in car_owners:
                    problem = str(registration_owner[0]) + ' - ' + str(registration_owner[1]) + ' não consta no CAR da propriedade'
                    item = FarmProblem(client=registration.client,farm=farm,context='CAR Owner',specific=registration.number,item=problem)
                    item.save()
```

As can be seen I start the view by deleting all records of nonconformities and do the checking and possible record of the items again.
Due to the nature of the application, this routine will occur several times and with that a massive amount of records will be constantly deleted/added. My question is if any part of this data is somehow stored in the database or in the app which would lead to a loss of performance. Or also if this routine could cause any harm in the future to the application.

Answer (score 1):

Deletion may cause the database to use more space than absolutely necessary, and frequent data manipulation may cause the data storage to become fragmented which may degrade performance.

Space can be reclaimed and data defragmented manually by issuing a [VACUUM](https://sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html) command in the SQLite3 console (shown below) or via `cursor.execute('VACUUM main')`:

```sql
sqlite> -- "main" is the name of the database to be vacuumed
sqlite> -- "main" is the default name of the sqlite3 database
sqlite> VACUUM main;
```

Note that `VACUUM`

- requires free disk space of twice the size of the database file for its operation
- may change the ROWIDs on tables that do not have an integer primary key
- will fail if there is an open transaction on the connection that is executing the `VACUUM` command

There is also an [AUTO_VACUUM](https://sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_auto_vacuum) PRAGMA statement that can (semi-)automatically release space used by deleted records after each commit.  However it does not defragment, and the documentation warns that it may consequently degrade performance.